# ggplot2: using the geom_area() function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame showing four classes for each year, along with their respective shares of the total for that year.

```
> head(df)
      class year share
1    class1 1975 0.806
2    class2 1975 0.131
3    class3 1975 0.018
4    class4 1975 0.045
5    class1 1976 0.788
6    class2 1976 0.151
```

When I run `ggplot` with no `fill` specified, I get a uniform gray box, as expected.

```
> ggplot(df, aes(x=year, y=share, group=class)) + geom_area() + scale_fill_brewer()
```

So I try to add `fill=class`, and it doesn't work.

```
> ggplot(df, aes(x=year, y=share, group=class, fill=class)) + geom_area() + scale_fill_brewer()

Error in inherits(x, "factor") : object "base_size" not found
In addition: Warning message:
In inherits(x, "factor") : restarting interrupted promise evaluation
>
```

What can I do to the `class` factor to get it working properly with `scale_fill_brewer()`? The idea, obviously, is to shade each area of the graph according to its class.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't get such an error message using the data sample you have showed us above, and everything works as expected. Maybe you could try closing and reopening the R session, and see if this helps.

Comment: Can you put together a runnable example?  I'm suspicious of using a reserved word like "class" as the name of your column.  Perhaps that's it?

Comment: I actually altered the column names to sterilize the data, so the problem was there before and after the "class" field name, but I'll make a new data.frame and post a runnable example.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem. It seams that

```
theme_set(theme_bw(base_size=9))
```

results in the error reported. But

```
base_size <- 9
theme_set(theme_bw(base_size=base_size))
```

works.

I googled and found the example at the [learnr blog](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/)

I dont know what the first example does not work though?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in some theme parameters I'd set, so it went away once I started building a runnable example to reproduce here. Thanks for the help.