# color in ggplot based on the sign of the variable using the Reshape library

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hey everyone I am using the inbuilt-dataset economics in Rstudio. I want to create a ggplot and display the personal savings rate (psavert) with different colors of positive and negative values in a time series. I tried the following code, however its not really helping :

```
new2 <-melt(economics, id=c("date"))
new2[["sign"]] = ifelse(new2[["value"]] >= 0, "positive", "negative")
ggplot(mydata2, aes(x = date, y = value, fill = sign)) + geom_area() + 
scale_fill_manual(values = c("positive" = "blue", "negative" = "red"))
```

I am unable to plot just the variable psavert. Thank you :)

Comment: How exactly do we get that `economics` data ...?

Comment: just use economics. R will read it itself.

Comment: @jhin It's inlucded in `ggplot2`.

Comment: Duplicates of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17959817/903061) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7883154/903061).

Comment: @Gregor im learning more about reshape and melt functions, and none of these solutions uses these.

Comment: Your `melt`ing is unnecessary with this data, the data is already tidy. It's also completely unrelated to the coloring of the ggplot.

Comment: @Gregor could please look into the code ad see what i am doing wrong.

Comment: I'll have time to answer later tonight if no one else has yet. I think it would help you a lot on to understand melt and when you need it to read through the [Tidy Data paper](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf).